# Can't find the issue while creating a dropdown list based on the selection of another dropdown list using Google App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dropdown list of subjects in F5 cell of a sheet named 'Dashboard'. The list of subjects (e.g. All, ICTE4113, HUM4115, PHY 4105) are coming from a another Tab named 'Master' where subjects are in column 6 and dates are in column 1.

> Now in G5 cell of Dashboard, I would like to see a dropdown list of
> only those unique dates related to the subject selected in F5 cell of
> the Dashboard. But it does not produce any dropdown list at all.

Obviuosly, these unique dates will come from the column 1 of the Master sheet. My codes are as follows:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var wsOptions = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master");
  var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues();
  
  function onEdit(e){
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F5');
    var val = range.getValue();
    
    if(val === "All"){
       dashboard.getRange('G5').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
       dashboard.getRange('G5').clearDataValidations();      
    }
    else{
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[6]});
      //console.log(listToApply);
      var cell = dashboard.getRange('G5');
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(listToApply).setAllowInvalid(false).build();`

      cell.setDataValidation(rule);            
    }      
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use cell.clearDataValidations() before applying a new one.

Comment: Could you provide a copy of your sheet so we can test and reproduce the issue? Thanks

Comment: @Marios Please note that it is for manual entry at F5 and G5 cell. The Sheet is at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PZmmhqGKC9vCaxRRBUj_YFSSvS4RwaS7Y7LWp1pwQs4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TamjidTaha I posted my solution. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @Marios currently the dropdown list is in ascending order but I need it to be in descending order, latest dates will come first. trying to solve these ways but can't do it //var optionss = options.sort({column: 1, ascending: false}); //var options2 = options.sort(descOrder); please advise.

Comment: I will check it tomorrow and try my best :)

Comment: @Marios could you please check my new post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176319/how-to-create-a-string-from-the-sheet-names-using-google-app-scripts

Comment: @TamjidTaha I answered it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You are very close.

There are two main issues in the code that are related to the same thing:

```
var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val});
var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[6]});
```

you filter based on **wrong** columns.

1. `filteredOptions` should filter on **column F**, therefore it should be `return o[5] === val`.
2. `listToApply` should filter on **column A**, therefore it should be `return o[0]`.

---

I also made a couple of changes:

- I use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead of [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to avoid getting the dates as **timestamps**.
- I clear the previous value in the dropdown menu after every selection:

  ```
  cell.clearContent();
  cell.clearDataValidations();
  ```

---

Last but not least, when you use `onEdit(e)` it is always a good idea to get a reference to the sheet and the cell that was edited using the `event` object.

For example, by using this if condition, you can ensure that your code will be executed **only** when there is an edit on cell **F5** in **Dashboard** sheet:

```
if (val_not =='F5' && as.getName() == "Dashboard") {code to be executed}
```

---

### Solution:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var wsOptions = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master");
  var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,6).getDisplayValues();
  
  function onEdit(e){

    var as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var val = e.range.getValue();
    var val_not = e.range.getA1Notation();
    
    if (val_not =='F5' && as.getName() == "Dashboard"){
    
    if(val === "All"){
       dashboard.getRange('G5').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
       dashboard.getRange('G5').clearDataValidations();      
    }
    else{
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[5] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[0]}).sort().reverse();
      
      var cell = dashboard.getRange('G5');
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(listToApply).setAllowInvalid(false).build();

      cell.clearContent();
      cell.clearDataValidations();
      cell.setDataValidation(rule);            
    }      
  } 
  }
```

Comment: could you please advise me how to sort the dropdownlist in descending order to find the latest dates are at the top of the list. Currently it is in ascending order. Thank you.

Comment: trying to solve these ways but can't do it //var optionss = options.sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
  //var options2 = options.sort(descOrder);

  //var listToApply2 = listToApply.sort({column: 1, ascending: false});

Comment: @TamjidTaha I updated my answer to sort the dropdown dates in descending order. Check it out :)

Comment: please note that your final code generates error message, "The data validation rule has more items than the limit of 500. Use the 'List from a range' criteria instead". Also note that the Master table contains 8-10K rows of data, from which the dropdown list is coming from. Thanks

Comment: @TamjidTaha thanks for the heads up. When I built the code the file had less rows. I think the error is self explanatory. You can't have a drop-down menu of more than 500 items. That's not a limitation of the solution. It's a limitation by Google . Would you like to post a new question regarding this issue ? It might worth the attention and other experts (including me) might be able to provide workarounds.

Comment: The dropdown list will not be more than 40 in my case. First we are selecting the subject for example ICTE4115, then it will search the relevant dates. For instance today 50 students responded in ICTE4115 but the date will be same, it should retrieve only todays date as just one item. So in total it is 40 unique dates per subject per semester. Even if we consider 10 subjects per semester, it won't be more than 400 dates as items in the drowdown list. The Master Sheet may have 5K rows of data but unique dates for a single subject will be approx 40 and for all subject 400. check plz

Comment: Share the new file with me or even better ask a new question and I will answer it . @TamjidTaha

Comment: As it is the original file, it is better for me to share it here rather than in a new post. The link is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uIs3NQUcNrp_5kdDZ_fGxGTmRI2CMaEg_W_0aQbLFhc/edit?usp=sharing   Please note that all the even number of subject code such as ICTE4216, ICTE4242, ICTE4244 are generating the list as these tabs have less than 500 rows of data now. others not generating the list for dropdown menu.

Comment: @TamjidTaha I will check it later and let you know.

Comment: Please do it on urgent basis if possible as we use it for students. Let me create a new post but there I will not supply the link of my google sheet there. Here I will update you with the post link within few minutes. Thank you.

Comment: Please check the post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016445/showing-errors-the-data-validation-rule-has-more-items-than-the-limit-of-500-u

Comment: @TamjidTaha I will be able to answer the question in about 3-4 hours from now. I hope the new one won't get closed because of lack of reproducibility.

Comment: could you please check the post above soon. Thank you.

Comment: @TamjidTaha I posted my answer there. However, since this is a heavier function, please be gentle when you select a subject in column F5. It takes  around 2 seconds to update the validation list :) . Rather than that, the solution works perfectly.